# window.document.forms[0].target='_blank'; not firing

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

i have an ascx file that is embedded in an aspx page with

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
    <div class="DivMain">
        <asp:MultiView >
  <cc1:TabPanel>
  <cc1:TabContainer >
                  <cc1:TabPanel ID="tbid" runat="server">
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label4" Text="sometext" Width="150px" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <uc1:Contracts runat="server" id="ucName" />
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </cc1:TabPanel>
```

The javascript lives on the main page is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
           
        function linkBtnNewTab() {          
             window.document.forms[0].target='_blank'; 
            
        }
    </script>
```

the ascx file has the following:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvTest" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                  <Columns>
                                   
                                     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="PDF" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                         <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnTest" OnClientClick="linkBtnNewTab()" OnClick="btnTest_Click" Text='<%# Bind("PdfName") %>'/>
                                             
                                             
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
             </asp:GridView>
```

when i put an alert in the function it displays but the new tab does not open.  when i use the following for testing purposes a tab opens up.  I cant use this because i will be populating the new tab with a pdf.  Is there a reason or way i can make the tab show?

```
window.open('https://www.google.com', '_blank')
```

Comment: Sometimes pop-up blocker can prevent new tab to be opened.

Comment: but it doesnt happen when i do a stand alone project -- only when in an ascx page

Comment: Changing target will not open a new tab. You also need to submit your form.

Comment: like i said above that code works in a stand alone aspx app-- but it does not work when you put it in a ascx